# Laravel + Vite + Sail over HTTPS. Possible?

Tags: laravel, https, vite, laravel-sail

After several hours to try things, I think I'm too much confuse to understand what's going wrong... The title explain perfectly what I'm trying to make working.
My `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    mysite.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '443:443' //added for test but not working...
            - '${HMR_PORT:-8080}:8080'
            - '5173:5173' //Vite port
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - minio
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-nginx:
        driver: local
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

My `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        https: true,
        host: '0.0.0.0'
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true
        }),
    ],
});
```

My `.env`:

```yaml
(...)
APP_URL=https://mysite.test
APP_SERVICE=mysite.test
(...)
```

The result of that configuration is it working with http://mysite.test but not in https. That return:

**This site can’t be reached**

**mysite.test unexpectedly closed the connection.**

Does anyone have a tips for me? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I managed to get this working with Caddy using the following gist
https://gist.github.com/gilbitron/36d48eb751875bebdf43da0a91c9faec

After all of the above I added the vite port to `docker-compose.yml` under `laravel.test` service.

```yaml
ports:
    - '5173:5173'
```

Also vite itself needs an ssl certificate

`vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl'

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        https: true,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost'
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        basicSsl(),
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

For some reason my app generates http links, not https. So I added the following to the `boot` method of my `AppServiceProvider.php`

```php
\URL::forceScheme('https');
```

Answer (score 3):

For load assets `@vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])` in https: add this line in .env: `ASSET_URL=https://midomain.com`

Answer (score 0):

Using the share command you can run a https tunnel through [expose](https://expose.dev/). Your domain will look like

> https://[something].expose.dev

Getting a real globally trusted ssl certificate can only be done by a certificate authority like for example Let's Encrypt. They need to verify you own the domain, either by a [http challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#http-01-challenge) or a [dns challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge).

As you cannot really own a .test domain, your only option left is [sign a certificate yourself](https://linuxize.com/post/creating-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate/) and add it to your own computer plus it's root certificate. If you do this only your computer will show the connection as secure though.